# Boto3 python script AMI backup create_image function doesn't accept TagSpecifications

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ami

The script I have created is working and it creates AMI backups of instances that uses certain Tags. (it works except when I add the `TagSpecifications` part)
My biggest issue now is that the Snapshots that are created for the AMI doesn't have any Tag name at all.

The error that I get is:

> Unknown parameter in input: "TagSpecifications", must be one of: BlockDeviceMappings, Description, DryRun, InstanceId, Name, NoReboot

It appears in the documentation but it is driving me crazy: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_image

Any idea what it could be?

```py
import boto3
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

session = boto3.Session(region_name="us-east-2")
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Backup', 'Values': ['Yes']}])


for instance in instances:
    instance_name = ''
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag["Key"] == 'Name':
            instance_name = tag["Value"]
    print(instance.id, "{0}-{1}".format(instance_name, today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
    instance.create_image(
        Name="{0}-{1}".format(instance_name, today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
        InstanceId=instance.id,
        Description='Quarterly-Backup-AMI',
        NoReboot=True,
        TagSpecifications=[
            {
                'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
                'Tags': [
                    {
                        'Key': 'Name',
                        'Value': 'Testing123123'
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`create_image` does not take `InstanceId` parameter since your `instance` is already [Instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) object.

Also for AMI, you need `image`, not `snapshot`:

```
    instance.create_image(
        Name="dddd",
        Description='Quarterly-Backup-AMI',
        NoReboot=True,
        TagSpecifications=[
            {
                'ResourceType': 'image',
                'Tags': [
                    {
                        'Key': 'Name',
                        'Value': 'Testing123123'
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    )
```

The command **works**. I verified it on my EC2 instance.